# Calculating the value of a column based on consecutive values of rows in another column

Tags: postgresql, computed-column

It is straight forward to compute column value based on values of other columns, e.g. `speed/time AS acceleration` where speed and time are columns. Is there a way to compute column's value based on consecutive `rows` values in other columns?

My database consists of points location coordinates (consecutive points), and for each point, I want to determine that point's bearing change from reference (true north). Here's more detail about the question:

```
TABLE:
+-----+-----+---------+
| lat | lon | bearing |
+-----+-----+---------+
| x0  | y0  |   b1    |
| x1  | y1  |         |
| x2  | y2  |         |
+-----+-----+---------+
```

Now I want to compute the bearing column(e.g. `b1`). From my research, bearing between two points is determined this way:
[image]

Then bearing B of (x<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>) from (x<sub>0</sub>,y<sub>0</sub>) is calculated as:

```
B = arctan(b,a)          .......(1)
```

where

b = sin[y<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>0</sub>] * cosx<sub>1</sub> .....(2)

a = cosx<sub>0</sub>* sinx<sub>1</sub> - sinx<sub>0</sub> * cosx<sub>1</sub> * [y<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>0</sub>]   ......(3)

Thus, to compute the bearing of `row1` in the above table (`b1`), both  quantities **a** and **b** in equations 2-3 require some value from `row2` in the table i.e. `x1,y1`, and addition to `x0, y0`

This is the computation I would like to do on the database, I have the latitude and longitude columns for the consecutive geolocations stored. I created [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e2ba1bd8826e1910c3495f3d67fdf330) so need to alter the table by adding a 5<sup>th</sup> column for `bearing`, but I am not sure how I can use values from next `row` for the current `row` in the bearing column.

Comment: Please add desured result for your fiddle, with all calculations for at least one record. *how I can use values from next row for the current row* LEAD/LAG. Recursive CTE, if nothing helps.

Comment: Theory is excess (interesting, but ewxcess nevertheless). Whereas the formula `bearing = some_expression(lon, lat, LAG(lon), LAG(lat))` would be very useful.

Comment: Anycase you need in something like https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3d8d7d15258bf8c18ab1d47ec78eb43c

Comment: in the fiddle I didn't create the bearing column.  My objective is to alter the table adding bearing column from the computation, but no idea how to.

Comment: Ah, thank you so for your help. I have been on this for two days. That's why good to talk in research process.

Comment: Show the result like the column already exists and fille, do not think about how to alter table and updatу data. Or simply edit my fiddle (maybe replace LEAD with LAG, maybe swap LON and LAT...).

Comment: That's fine. This gives me the very best step to go ahead with my research. I was like not to ask, wondering if such operations are possible in databases, or I would look stupid for asking silly quesition. Many thanks.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I refer you to the bearing section on this page https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: And page 363 ( page4) of this paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0968090X17303509

Comment: Your formulas are good for rhumb line calculations at low to middle latitudes and small separations. They will become progressively less accurate as distances increase and as you approach the poles. You may wish to research Great Circle formulas.

Comment: @MichaelGreen thank you for this input. I will research on that too.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing you need is an ordering of the rows, since rows are unordered per se. Once you have an ordering, you can use the window function `lag` to access the previous row in that ordering.

Assuming that your rows are ordered by `tstamp`, that would look like

```
SELECT lat,
       lon,
       lag(lat) OVER (ORDER BY tstamp) AS prev_lat,
       lag(lon) OVER (ORDER BY tstamp) AS prev_lon
FROM atable;
```

Applying the formula of your choice is left as an exercise for the reader.